# jQuery Function Should Only Run After a Specific Window Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, resize, window

I am trying to add some conditions to a jQuery function so that it only loads when the window size is above a specific width. It runs correctly based on the initial size of the window, but if the window is re-sized after the page loads it does not change.

Code:

```
    var doStuff = function() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (windowWidth >= 768) {
            DO STUFF
    }
}
$(window).load(function () {
    doStuff();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    doStuff();
});
```

For example, if I load the page in a window that's 960px wide and then resize my window down to 600px, the doStuff function will still trigger. (But if I load my page at 600px the function will not trigger--and it still wont trigger if I increase my window size to 960px.)

Comment: [Your current code shouldn't do that](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XcV8L/). Can you provide an example of the problem? Edit: perhaps [this variation](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XcV8L/1/) can help you.

Comment: Works for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL6VC/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/rYK87/